# Error al utilizar el atributo multiple en un s:file de struts2.0

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

La siguiente línea de código no me compila al verla en el navegador, me marca un Error 500 al tratar de acceder a la página con esta línea. Según yo uso struts2.0 en mi aplicación, y lo que encontré en internet con struts2 es posible utilizar atributos como el de multiple en tag file de struts. ¿Por qué me marca error?

```
<s:file name="image" multiple="multiple"/>
```

Según leí estas opciones se habilitaron en la versión 2.1 de struts en adelante, tengo yo la 2.0 Habrá manera de utilizar estas opciones en la versión 2.0?

Creen que si lo trabajo así:

```
<input type="file" name="x" multiple/>
```

Me funcione igual en los actiones del struts?

Comment: Sería bueno compartieras un poco más de código... tu action, configuración para el upload de los archivos, si es por array, list,etc. Igual dar una vuelta en la documentación Struts2: [File - Struts 2](http://struts.apache.org/docs/file-upload.html)

Comment: Hola, Ventur. Recién empiezo a trabar sobre struts. No serviría de nada compartir más código, y aún no tengo el action, simplemente es el jsp que cuando entro me marca error, el que sí quisiera compartirles es la configuración del upload pero no tengo idea dónde está.

Comment: Con la información que das, no es posible ayudarte de una mejor manera, lee los logs del servidor de aplicación, puede proveer información sobre el error, en la web busca un ejemplo con Struts2.

Comment: Hay muchisimos ejemplos. Y es sobre lo que me estoy basando. He empezado con el html pero me marca error al ponerle multiple a la etiqueta. Seguro es cosa de versiones,pero debe haber alternativa, tal vez alguien se haya topado con esto ya

Comment: Has trabajado con Struts2? Crees que si pongo el input type file normalmente pueda trabajar bien en el action con archivos múltiples?